# Managing ALLOWED_HOSTS in Django for Kubernetes health check

Tags: python, django, kubernetes, devops

I have a Django application running on Kubernetes, using an API for health checks. The issue I'm facing is that every time the IP associated with Django in Kubernetes changes, I have to manually update ALLOWED_HOSTS.

**django code:**

```
class HealthViewSet(ViewSet):
    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False)
    def health(self, request):
        try:
            return Response('OK', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response({'response': 'Internal server error'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

**deployment code :**

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health/
    port: 8000
  initialDelaySeconds: 15
  timeoutSeconds: 5
```

**Error:**

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192.168.186.79:8000'. You may need to add '192.168.186.79' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 135, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 148, in get_host
    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192.168.186.79:8000'. You may need to add '192.168.186.79' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Bad Request: /health/
```

Is there a way to dynamically use ALLOWED_HOSTS and avoid manual updates? (Every deployment IP changed.)

**ALLOWED_HOSTS**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

Any guidance or suggestions for the best solution in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware to selectively disable the allowed_hosts check for the url you use for health checks.

Comment: Please update your answer to include a full, working solution with code. Currently, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting checks the Host header sent on an HTTP request, so you can simply [configure the headers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#http-probes) sent by your liveliness probe:

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health/
    port: 8000
    httpHeaders:
      - name: host
        value: your.hostname.here # Configure the appropriate host here
  initialDelaySeconds: 15
  timeoutSeconds: 5
```